# Can't add flex-grow for column flex box with min-height

Tags: html, css, reactjs, flexbox

I am trying to design a website layout that uses the power of flex box in order to fill the entire page with content even when the content does not fill the entire length of the page.

I have created a big flex-box container with `flex-direction: column;`. When I set the last child's to have `flex-grow: 1;` and all of the rest of the childrens have `flex-grow: unset;` something breaks and the `flex-grow` property does not affect the content of the children when I am using `min-height`

refer to the following [example on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ShaharIlany/xq9Ljkeh/15/).

The `.should-strech` class represents the content of one of the childrens that should fill the entire children's height. When I am using `height: 100px` everything works well (See the first box, the yellow area fills the entire space).

When I am using `min-height: 100px;` The yellow area does not fills the entire height anymore.

I tried using another flex box inside the child but it is not a best practice for my situation becuase this is a generic component that the number of "contents" in a children is unknown or dynamic.

```html
 <div class="container height">
  <div class="child">
    1
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <div class="should-strech">
      2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br/>
<div class="container min-height">
  <div class="child">
    1
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <div class="should-strech">
      2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
.min-height {
   min-height: 100px;
}

.height {
   height: 100px;
}

.container {
  width: 100px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: aqua;
}

.child {
  background-color: red;
}

.child:last-child {
  background-color: green;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.should-strech {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: your only way is to consider another Flexbox or CSS grid inside

Comment: I tried to contain it in another flexbox and it didn't worked. Do you have an example for a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a nested flexbox like below:

```css
.min-height {
   min-height: 100px;
}

.height {
   height: 100px;
}

.container {
  width: 100px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: aqua;
}

.child {
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.child:last-child {
  background-color: green;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.should-strech {
  background-color: yellow;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container height">
  <div class="child">
    1
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <div class="should-strech">
      2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br/>
<div class="container min-height">
  <div class="child">
    1
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <div class="should-strech">
      2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```